# Looping in SPSS to work through the cases

Tags: spss

I have a data set in SPSS containing a sequence of six variables from which I have to create a new variable which should contain the last value present in the sequence. Let's say the data look like this: (the second row contains all missing values but represents a case to which I'll merge some other variables later, so I need this too.)

```
DATA LIST  /V1 TO V6 1-6.
BEGIN DATA
423451

73453
929
0257
END DATA.
```

Now if I wish to generate a variable named `lastscr` which should have values `1, ., 3, 9, 7`. Can anyone help me on how should I do it in SPSS? I could not find any clue about it. Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can easily be done with the `DO REPEAT` command:

```
DO REPEAT Var = V1 TO V6.
   IF NOT(SYSMIS(Var)) lastscr = Var.
END REPEAT.
```